# Getting a county name using a 5 digit FIPS code

Tags: python-3, library, fips

Lets say I have a five digit fips code: '13245'. I have a dictionary to handle know that the 2-digit state part of the code(ex: {'GA':'13', etc...}). But I want to also get the full county name (EX: 13 - GA, 245 - Richmond County). Is there a library, mod, or API that will help me achieve this?

Comment: https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/codes/cou.html and set the pull down to "united states".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the URL constructor may choke when fed a fips code lower than 10000.

Try code 1001 (Autauga County)

Hence my suggestion for the URLS constructor, using `'{0:05d}'.format(fipsCD)`:

```
import requests
import urllib

fipsCD =  1001
url = 'https://www.broadbandmap.gov/broadbandmap/census/county/fips/' + '{0:05d}'.format(fipsCD) + '?format=json'
data = requests.get(url).json()
print(data['Results']['county'][0]['name'])
```

Answer (score 2):

The FCC provides an API that will return attributes of a FIPS unit. https://www.broadbandmap.gov/developer/api/census-api-by-fips-code

Note however, the page says that it is no longer being updated since 2014 and I cannot find a similar tool anywhere on the new site that is linked there.

```py
import requests
import urllib

#FIPS code
fipsCD = 13245

#Construct URL
url = 'https://www.broadbandmap.gov/broadbandmap/census/county/fips/' + str(fipsCD) + '?format=json'

#Retreive information and parse
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()

#Extract county name
countyNM = data['Results']['county'][0]['name']

print(countyNM)
```

Comment: This looks good. Quick questions; when I try `countyNM = data['Results']['county'][0]['name']` it throws an error: `TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable`. Is there something I am leaving out here?

Comment: You get that error from directly pasting the code from my answer in? What is the result if you enter `print(response.text)` ?

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. I left the `()` off of the `data = response.json`. Its working now.